# Can I declare a variable in an “if statement”?

Tags: c++, if-statement, variables, declaration

I am writing a "vending machine" program and I need to have 5 items where 3 items cost an integer amount and the other 2 cost a decimal amount.

I am only using `if` statements in this code, but there is an error with my `cost` variable.

What did I do wrong?

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  cout << "Vending Machine" << endl;
  cout << "----Items------" << endl;
  cout << "1. Popcorn: $2" << endl;
  cout << "2. Coconut Clusters: $3" << endl;
  cout << "3. Granola Bar: $2.50" << endl;
  cout << "4. Trail Mix: $1.50" << endl;
  cout << "5. Chocolate: $1" << endl;

  cout << "Enter you selection: " << flush;
  int input;
  cin >> input;


  if (input == 1) {
    cout << "You added Popcorn to your cart." << endl;
    float cost = 2;
    cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
  }
  
  if (input == 2) {
    cout << "You added Coconut Clusters to your cart." << endl;
    float cost = 3;
    cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
  }
  
  if (input == 3) {
    cout << "You added Granola Bar to your cart." << endl;
    float cost = 2.50;
    cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
  }

  if (input == 4) {
    cout << "You added Trail Mix to your cart." << endl;
    float cost = 1.50;
    cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
  }

  if (input == 5) {
    cout << "You added Chocolate to your cart." << endl;
    float cost = 1;
    cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
  } 

  

  cout << "Pay amount: " << flush;
  float money;
  cin >> money;

  if (money > cost) {
    float change = money-cost;
    cout << "Thank you! You have $" << change << " change." << endl;
  }

  if (money == cost) {
    cout << "Thank you! Have a nice day!." << endl;
  }

  if (money < cost) {
    float amountOwed = cost-money;
    cout << "Please insert another $" << amountOwed << endl;

    cout << "Enter amount: " << flush;
    float payment;
    cin >> payment;

    if (payment > amountOwed) {
    float change2 = payment-cost;
    cout << "Thank you! You have $" << change2 << " change." << endl;
    }

    if (payment == amountOwed) {
      cout << "Thank you! Have a nice day!." << endl;
    }

    if (payment < amountOwed) {
      cout << "Sorry, you did not enter enough money. Your cart has emptied." << endl;
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at **scope** of your variables.

Comment: You can declare a variable anywhere. How long it lives is defined by scope. In this case your `cost` variable are only alive inside the '{}` inside the if block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing the following:

```
int main()
{
    [...]
    if (input == 1) {
        cout << "You added Popcorn to your cart." << endl;
        float cost = 2;
        cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
    }
    [...]
    if (money > cost) {
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

The [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) of the variable `cost` is limited to the `if` block, because that is where you declare it. Therefore, the variable does not exist anymore when you evaluate the expression `money > cost`.

To fix this, you should instead declare the variable `cost` in the main block scope of the function, like this:

```
int main()
{
    float cost;

    [...]
    if (input == 1) {
        cout << "You added Popcorn to your cart." << endl;
        cost = 2;
        cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
    }
    [...]
    if (money > cost) {
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I try to compile your code, I get the following error message:

`Error: ‘cost’ was not declared in this scope`

In order to fix this error, you just need to declare `cost` variable in the *function's main block [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)*, for example like this:

```
int main()
{
    float cost;

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I added that in my code but now the change is not properly computed. For example, when i pay $1 for a $3 item, the change is $1 instead of owing $2. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @AyushJain: It was a pleasure to help you. I believe your answer would have received more upvotes if you had also posted code, in order to illustrate what you were saying. That is probably the reason why my answer received more upvotes than yours. People normally like to see a nice mixture of code and text explaining the code. :-) However, I am sometimes too lazy to do that and just write a short answer (which gives me less upvotes). But you don't have to change your answer now to add code, I just wanted to tell you how to get more upvotes in future answers.

Comment: I have made some slight changes to your answer, to illustrate what you are saying with code. If you don't like my changes, feel free to revert them.

Answer (score 2):

> "Can I declare a variable in an “if statement”?"

Yes. For example:

```
if (auto foo = bar())
```

The variable `foo` will be valid inside the body of the `if` statement and will be initialized to whatever `bar()` returns and the body of the `if` will be entered if `foo` converts to a `bool` value of `true`.

Since C++17 you can also do:

```
if (auto foo = bar(); foo == 42)
```

Again, the variable `foo` will be declared and valid inside the `if` and initialized by `bar()`, but you now have more control over when to *enter* the `if` body.

Comment: I'm afraid the OP has invalided your answer by changing the title of the question.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Seems you are right. I'll still leave it here, in case someone else needs an answer to the *original* question.

Comment: Meanwhile, someone else has edited the question and restored the original title, so your question is no longer invalidated. But now we have the same problem as before, namely that the question title does not correspond to the question text.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: you've just changed your question to add `float cost = 0;` in a suitable place.  Now you need to remove the `float` keyword from the attempted assignments inside each `if (input ==` block: e.g. change `float cost = 2.50;` to `cost = 2.50;` so it changes the function-scope `cost` variable, instead of creating an extra `if`-scope variable.

---

Addressing your original problem...

Your `if` blocks...

```
if (input == 3) {
    cout << "You added Granola Bar to your cart." << endl;
    float cost = 2.50;
    cout << "Your total is $" << cost << endl;
}
```

...each create a `float cost` variable local to the scope of that `if`, so after the `}` the value of `cost` that you set is gone.  Instead, you need to have:

```
float cost;
```

Before your first `if (input == ...` statement, so its lifetime extends to the end of the enclosing function scope (i.e. until `main()` returns).

Comment: Please note that meanwhile, someone else has edited the question and has reverted OP's edit to the code mentioned in your "update", thereby invalidating your "update". I think this edit by someone else was appropriate, because OP's changes invalidated both your answer and my answer. But I'm afraid that now you will have to update your "update".

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: thanks for the heads-up.  I think I"ll just delete my answer soon - you have this covered.  Cheers